# For loop using mutate comparing two data frames

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I have two dataframes with same variable names, the first with values, the second with shadow variables. I want to mutate variables on df1 according to the value in df2 (if df2$x > 90 then I want to mutate df1$x to NA).

```
# Example input dataframes
df1 <- data.frame(
    x = c(123, 456, 789),
    y = c(120, 745, 789),
    z = c(852, 741, 963)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
    x = c(1, 95, 96),
    y = c(1, 99, 1),
    z = c(98, 1, 1)
)
```

What I want to obtain is a dataframe that looks like this:

```
#        x       y      z 
#1      123     120      NA         
#2      NA      NA      741         
#3      NA      789     963
```

I get the result I want with:

```
result <- df1%>%
  mutate(x= replace(x, df2$x > 90 , NA  )) %>%
  mutate(y= replace(y, df2$y > 90 , NA )) %>%
  mutate(z= replace(z, df2$z > 90 , NA ))
```

But I would like to use a for loop instead because I have several variables. I tried with:

```
for (i in c("x" , "y" , "z") {
 result <- df1%>%
  mutate(i= replace(i, df2$i > 90 , NA  )) 
}
```

But didn't work... so I'm here asking for your kind guidance. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

**1) across** This works to process all columns:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  mutate(across(.fn = ~ replace(., df2[[cur_column()]] > 90, NA)))
##     x   y   z
## 1 123 120  NA
## 2  NA  NA 741
## 3  NA 789 963
```

### Loop

**2) loop with across** Regarding the loop in the question, one can use mutate(across(...)) for  that.  We first make a copy of df1 to preserve the input.  The result is in df1_na.

```
library(dplyr)
df1_na <- df1
for(nm in names(df1)) {
  df1_na <- df1_na %>% mutate(across(all_of(nm), ~ replace(., df2[[nm]] > 90, NA)))
}
```

**3) rlang** or using rlang:

```
library(dplyr)
df1_na <- df1
for(nm in names(df1)) {
  df1_na <- df1_na %>% mutate({{nm}} := replace(.[[nm]], df2[[nm]] > 90, NA))
}
```

**4) base** or a loop with only base (although a simpler base solution is provided in another answer).

```
df1_na <- df1
for(nm in names(df1)) df1_na[[nm]] <- replace(df1_na[[nm]], df2[[nm]] > 90, NA)
```

Comment: thank you!! I tried with option 2 but some zeros in df2 were converted to NA as well in df1. I just added a second line of mutate changing > 90 to ==0 and it's done.

Comment: Zeros in df2 would not cause NA's to appear in df1 so there must be something not shown going on.  If you can *edit the question* to provide a second test case where this occurs we can try to address it.

Comment: my bad! I used a wrong df, now it's working without the extra line haha thanks again

Answer (score 1):

We can use `replace`

```
replace(df1, df2 > 90, NA)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the two dataframes are of same dimension you can do -

```
df1[df2 > 90] <- NA
df1

#    x   y   z
#1 123 120  NA
#2  NA  NA 741
#3  NA 789 963
```